# Using bootstrap, I want to reproduce this navigation menu (picture inside)

Tags: navbar

I'm trying to reproduce this effect (https://i.stack.imgur.com/WifXL.jpg) using Bootstrap. What's the structure I need to do in order to achieve the same result as in the picture? Do I place a  behind the  ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

New answer after comments:
I've done something, I think, similar you want at my test page: http://test15.variart.org/

Steps:
Customize Bootstrap properties:

- in 'Navbar' section set 'transparent' of: @navbar-default-bg, @navbar-default-toggle-hover-bg, @navbar-default-brand-hover-bg, @navbar-default-toggle-border-color - you can also try to change other properties (just try yourself)
  This will set transparent background in a entire navbar and 'hamburger' button
- in 'Grid system' section set extra big @grid-float-breakpoint, e.g. 1000000px
  This will set 'hamburger' menu as 'default'

Next look at Bootstrap page - navbar section in Components - there is first example shows where to put menu items that will be collapsed:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
```

change it to something like:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">
```

- of course you can change this background color

Hope, it will help.

Old answer:
From the tag you choose, I understand that you want to collapse the navbar when user uses e.g. mobile phone?
In that case you should use example code from bootstrap website: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default

This code do this for you - this is copy from mentioned website:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, I'm trying to erase the background color of the navbar so that when on mobile only the hamburger icon and the logo are visible (as shown in the picture).

Comment: Do you want to erase the bg even if it is not on mobile?

Comment: Yes, I would like that if possible.